# Why my method of server side can not be consume json object from my request from android but another json object is ok?

Tags: java, android, jersey, gson

I'm trying to send an json object to server written by jersey. I was tested it by postman. When i use my class want to send, it can be read by server (null object). But when i replace the object i want to send by another object. It's work. I still don't know what happen with it.

I tried send a object (FilmWatched.class) like this: 
{
    "id_film": "F04",
    "cur_progress": 120,
    "username_": "tony123"
}

But method of my server side just read a null object from it. When i repalce it by another object (Profile.class) and fix a little bit in method params to read Profile object and it's work, the moethod of server side can read all information from the json. Here it's:

{
    "username": "tony123",
    "fistName": "Tony",
    "lastName": "Stark",
    "image": "tony123.png"
}

FilmWatched.class

```
public class FilmWatched {

@SerializedName("id_film")
@Expose
private String id_film;
@SerializedName("cur_progress")
@Expose
private int cur_progress;
@SerializedName("username_")
@Expose
private String username_;

public FilmWatched() {
    super();
}

public FilmWatched(String idFilm, int curProgress, String username) {
    super();
    this.id_film = idFilm;
    this.cur_progress = curProgress;
    this.username_ = username;
}
//....getter and setter....
}
```

Profile.class

```
public class Profile {
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;

@SerializedName("fistName")
@Expose
private String fistName;

@SerializedName("lastName")
@Expose
private String lastName;

@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String image;

public Profile() {
    super();
}

public Profile(String username, String fistName, String lastName,
        String image) {
    this.username = username;
    this.fistName = fistName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.image = image;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
//....getter and setter....
}
```

And this is my method of server side:

```
@Path("/Film")
public class FilmService {

@PUT
@Path("Update/WatchedFilm/")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public Response updateFilmWatched(FilmWatched filmWatched)
{
    boolean response= false;
    //update data when it was read
    DBConnector db = new DBConnector();
    boolean isUpdated = db.updateFilmWatched(filmWatched);
    //log some thing in consolse and response to client
    String s = isUpdated ? "Time progress updated" : "Cannot update Time progress";
    response = isUpdated ? true : false;
    System.out.println(s);

    return  Response.
            status(Response.Status.OK).
            entity(new Gson().toJson(response)).
            build();
}
}
```

I want method of server side can read json of object FilmWatched.

Comment: I solve this issue. By the way change parameter in method "updateFilmWatched" of server side. 
FilmWatched  -> String ... Then i convert it to json.